# Spring boot - gson singleton?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My application currently runs Gson instead of jackson, how do I use gson to parse an incoming form submit?

I currently get

> 2015-10-26 14:14:59.027 ERROR 12876 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.exp.controllers.UserController       : Bean object must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bean object must not be null

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private GsonHttp gsonHttp;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @RequestMapping(value="/createPOST", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseData createPOST(String json) {
    User user = null;
    try {
      user = gsonHttp.getGson().fromJson(json, User.class);
      userDao.save(user);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseData(false, Arrays.asList("Error with user creation."));
    }
    return new ResponseData(true, Arrays.asList(user));
  }
}
```

with this:

```
@Repository
public class GsonHttp {

    private Gson gson;

    public GsonHttp(){
        this.gson = new Gson();
    }

    public Gson getGson() {
        return gson;
    }

    public void setGson(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to map all this manually? If you just have the appropriate converters (which Spring Boot should add for you if Gson is on the classpath), you can declare a `@ModelAttribute User user` as a parameter, and all of this is automatic.

Comment: What happens when you change GsonHttp to be annotated with @Component instead??? Also often times generic classes like GsonHttp would be placed in generic packages. But to be autowired it needs to be in a subpackage of your main application configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Bean object must not be null" is thrown by the repository when you try to save a null object.

```
userDao.save(user) //User is null
```

The reason your object is null is because you can't get the json without adding @RequestBody so change your json parameter to have this annotation

```
public String createPost(@RequestBody String json) { //Added @RequestBody
```

## Setting up GSON in Spring Boot

By default Jackson is the default parser, as you explained, to replace this with GSON it's this easy.

src/main/resources/application.properties

> spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper.gson=true

This requires GSON on the classpath as you apparently do.

Then rewrite your create post method as so

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/createPOST", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseData createPOST(@RequestBody User user) {
    userDao.save(user);
    return new ResponseData(true, Arrays.asList(user));
  }
```

> Base HTTPMessageConverterClass - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.java

-

> Gson Specific Config - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/GsonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.java

Make sure to take special notice of the PreferGsonOrMissingJacksonCondition class in that last source. It uses GSON if gson is configured to be preferred or if Gson is on the classpath and jackson is not(Such as if you excluded it from Maven or Gradle)